# where does exeutable app made by JPackage save its local resources

Tags: javafx, windows-installer, java-11, jlink, jpackage

I chose to put my SQLite database files in local resources and packaged my application using JPackage.

The issue is whenever I delete the application from my desktop and reinstall it, the database data don't get deleted (with the deletion of the app), so I assumed the local resources are getting saved somewhere else on the desktop (after installing the app) other than the app directory, how can I find where they have been saved?

I'm using JLink-badass plugin to package it and here are its parameters :

```
jlink {
jpackage {
    installerName = 'demo'
    installerType = 'msi'
    installerOptions = [
            '--description', 'demo',
            '--copyright', 'Copyrigth 2021-2021 demo'
    ]
    installerOptions += ['--win-menu', '--win-shortcut']
 
}

launcher {
    name = 'demo'
```

Comment: But then you could only use it as a read-only database and I even don't know whether you can make a connection to the database as a resource. I prefer to copy out such resources into an external folder on first launch.

Comment: @mipa you can make a connection to the database as a resource. The issue that I met with copying the resources to an external folder (Putting it in /src/main directory as an example ) is after packaging my application the directory to my database changes, and so the application doesn't connect to it anymore

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. I meant to add some code to your application that extracts the packaged database to some external folder (like <home>/.myapp/) when your users first launch it on their systems. It's a typical behaviour that apps store data in some app specific folder.

Comment: @mipa sorry if this question is out of the main question of the post, but do you have any suggested way/tutorial to do so?

Comment: No, sorry and I also don't have the time to dig that up from my own code at the moment.

Comment: @slaw i have eventually found the ressource files (juste DataBases ones) in \AppData\Local\Temp directory, which explained why the database data are not getting deleted after deleting the app, still not sure why they are getting saved there and how can i make them getting saved in the app directory.

Comment: Maybe the SQLite JDBC driver extracts the resource to a temporary file?

Comment: @Slaw, i'm not sure if it's a default thing or not, since i did not configure anything related to this behaviour, it's really useless what i try, always getting saved in \AppData\Local\Temp, which is surelly unsafe place to store important data

Comment: Assuming you're using the "xerial" driver, looks like it extracts the resource into a temporary file. You can see this in [the source code](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/ada2b147dc858ef557a995e2f4ef25f7c65fc6a7/src/main/java/org/sqlite/SQLiteConnection.java#L207). Though it also looks like it will delete any existing temporary database file if the resource's last-modified time is more recent. Anyways, perhaps the SQLite library can't handle operating on a database file embedded in a JAR file, and so the driver has no choice but to extract it to a real file.

Answer (score 3):

Just consider the files inside the app-image or the package as immutable.
However you can still store data in e.g. the user's home directory. This has the advantage you can uninstall or upgrade the application to another version and still access the data where it was stored.